# How do I use GitOps to test & deploy my application to Heroku with GitLab CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I have a Heroku application that I deploy with `git push heroku master && heroku run rails db:migrate`.

I use GitLab to store my code, but I want to be able to:

- Test every push and merge request
- Deploy to a staging environment
- Deploy to production

All without leaving my command-line.

Also, while my stack uses Ruby on Rails, the answer doesn't necessarily have to use Rails. It should easily be adaptable to any stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just published [a blog post](https://www.toptal.com/platform/staff/posts/preview?post_id=120598) with all this plus illustrations, and a complete and public sample application. However, the gist of it is this:

**Step 1: Setup your Heroku apps**

Create two Heroku apps for staging and production. I'm going to call mine `toptal-pipeline` and `toptal-pipeline-staging`, the former is the production app.

Note your auth token using `heroku auth:token`.

**Step 2: Setup GitLab CI**

Paste this into `.gitlab-ci.yml` at the root of your project, substituting the values for `APPNAME_PRODUCTION` and `APPNAME_STAGING` with your Heroku app names respectively:

```
image: ruby:2.4

before_script:
  - >
   : "${HEROKU_EMAIL:?Please set HEROKU_EMAIL in your CI/CD config vars}"
  - >
   : "${HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN:?Please set HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN in your CI/CD config vars}"
  - curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-standalone.sh | sh
  - |
    cat >~/.netrc <<EOF
    machine api.heroku.com
      login $HEROKU_EMAIL
      password $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN
    machine git.heroku.com
      login $HEROKU_EMAIL
      password $HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN
    EOF
  - chmod 600 ~/.netrc
  - git config --global user.email "ci@example.com"
  - git config --global user.name "CI/CD"

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  APPNAME_PRODUCTION: toptal-pipeline
  APPNAME_STAGING: toptal-pipeline-staging

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    POSTGRES_USER: test
    POSTGRES_PASSSWORD: test-password
    POSTGRES_DB: test
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSSWORD}@postgres/${POSTGRES_DB}
    RAILS_ENV: test
  services:
    - postgres:alpine
  before_script:
    - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -yqq nodejs libpq-dev
    - curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
    - source ~/.bashrc
    - yarn
    - gem install bundler  --no-ri --no-rdoc
    - bundle install -j $(nproc) --path vendor
    - bundle exec rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=test
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
    - bundle exec rubocop


deploy_to_staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://$APPNAME_STAGING.herokuapp.com/
  script:
    - git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/$APPNAME_STAGING.git
    - git push heroku master
    - heroku pg:backups:capture --app $APPNAME_PRODUCTION
    - heroku pg:backups:restore `heroku pg:backups:url --app $APPNAME_PRODUCTION` --app $APPNAME_STAGING --confirm $APPNAME_STAGING
    - heroku run rails db:migrate --app $APPNAME_STAGING
  only:
    - master
    - tags

deploy_to_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://$APPNAME_PRODUCTION.herokuapp.com/
  script:
    - git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/$APPNAME_PRODUCTION.git
    - git push heroku master
    - heroku pg:backups:capture --app $APPNAME_PRODUCTION
    - heroku run rails db:migrate --app $APPNAME_PRODUCTION
  only:
    - /^v(?'MAJOR'(?:0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))\.(?'MINOR'(?:0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))\.(?'PATCH'(?:0|(?:[1-9]\d*)))(?:-(?'prerelease'[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+(?'build'[0-9A-Za-z-]+(\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?$/
    # semver pattern above is adapted from https://github.com/semver/semver.org/issues/59#issuecomment-57884619
```

Be sure to adapt the `deploy_to_staging` and `deploy_to_production` sections' `script` blocks to match your deployment steps if you're not using Ruby on Rails.

Also, do the same for your `test` block. This current one runs Rspec and Rubocop.

**Step 3: Configure your GitLab settings**

1. Add two secret variables to your GitLab CI settings

   - `HEROKU_EMAIL`: Your login email for Heroku
   - `HEROKU_AUTH_TOKEN`: Your token from step 1.
2. Add `v*` tags to protected tags in your GitLab Repository settings.

**Step 4: Create NPM scripts to make semantic versioning easier**

Add `standard-version` to your `devDependencies` with `yarn add --dev standard-version` and add the following scripts to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "release": "standard-version",
  "major": "yarn release --release-as major",
  "minor": "yarn release --release-as minor",
  "patch": "yarn release --release-as patch"
}
```

Also, add a version number to your `package.json` file:

```
"version": "0.0.7"
```

**Step 5: Write your code**

How your new coding workflow will be:

1. Write code
2. Git push to run tests
3. Git push to the `master` to deploy to staging
4. Tag a release using [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) and push to deploy to production

Also, to tag with a new semantic version number, run:

- `yarn patch` to increment the patch number. E.g. `x.x.1` => `x.x.2`
- `yarn minor` to increment the minor number. E.g. `x.1.x` => `x.2.x`
- `yarn major` to increment the major number. E.g. `1.x.x` => `2.x.x`

Go forth and build something awesome.